# Cx_Oracle fetch crash

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

So I've queried data from oracle database using cursor.execute(). A relatively simple select query. It works.

But when I try to fetch data from it, python crashes.

The same occurs for fetchall(), fetchmany() and fetchone().

When the query first broke in fetchmany() I decided to loop through fetchone() and it worked for the first two rows then broke at the third.

I'm guessing it is because there's too much data in third row.

So, is there any way to bypass this issue and pull the data?

(Please ignore the wrong indents could not copy properly in my phone)

EDIT: 
I removed four columns with type "ROWID". There was no issue after that. I was easily able to fetch 100 rows in one go.

So to confirm my suspicion I went ahead and created another copy with only those rowed columns and it crashes as expected.

So is there any issue with ROWID type?

Test table for the same.

Insert into TEST_FOR_CX_ORACLE (Z$OEX0_LINES,Z$OEX0_ORDER_INVOICES,Z$OEX0_ORDERS,Z$ITEM_ROWID) values ('ABoeqvAEyAAB0HOAAM','AAAL0DAEzAAClz7AAN','AAAVeuABHAAA4vdAAH','ABoeo+AIVAAE6dKAAQ');
Insert into TEST_FOR_CX_ORACLE (Z$OEX0_LINES,Z$OEX0_ORDER_INVOICES,Z$OEX0_ORDERS,Z$ITEM_ROWID) values ('ABoeqvABQAABKo6AAI','AAAL0DAEzAAClz7AAO','AAAVeuABHAAA4vdAAH','ABoeo+AIVAAE6dKAAQ');
Insert into TEST_FOR_CX_ORACLE (Z$OEX0_LINES,Z$OEX0_ORDER_INVOICES,Z$OEX0_ORDERS,Z$ITEM_ROWID) values ('ABoeqvABQAABKo6AAG','AAAL0DAEzAAClz7AAP','AAAVeuABHAAA4vdAAH','ABoeo+AHIAAN+OIAAM');
Insert into TEST_FOR_CX_ORACLE (Z$OEX0_LINES,Z$OEX0_ORDER_INVOICES,Z$OEX0_ORDERS,Z$ITEM_ROWID) values ('ABoeqvAEyAAB0HOAAK','AAAL0DAEzAACl0EAAC','AAAVeuABHAAA4vdAAH','ABoeo+AHIAAN+OIAAM');

Script:

```
from cx_Oracle import makedsn,connect,Cursor
from pandas import read_sql_table, DataFrame, Series

from time import time

def create_conn( host_link , port , service_name , user_name , password ):
    dsn=makedsn(host_link,port,service_name=service_name)
    return connect(user=user_name, password=password, dsn=dsn)

def initiate_connection(conn):
    try:
        dbconnection = create_conn(*conn)
        print('Connected to '+conn[2]+' !')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        dbconnection = None
    return dbconnection        

def execute_query(query,conn):
    dbconnection=initiate_connection(conn)
    try:
        cursor = dbconnection.cursor()
        print ('Cursor Created!')
        return cursor.execute(query)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return None

start_time = time()

query='''SELECT * FROM test_for_cx_oracle'''

try:
    cx_read_query = execute_query(query,ecspat_c)
    time_after_execute_query = time()
    print('Query Executed')
    columns = [i[0] for i in cx_read_query.description]
    time_after_getting_columns = time()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


print(time_after_execute_query-start_time,time_after_getting_columns-time_after_execute_query)
```

Comment: Can you try without pandas? In other words, just perform the query with cx_Oracle directly?

Comment: Yes I did. All I did was run "fetchone()". It returned output for two rows then crashed on the third.

Comment: Please check the details added in the EDIT

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in the Oracle Client libraries. You will see it if you attempt to fetch the same rowid value multiple times in consecutive rows. If you avoid that situation all is well. You can also set the environment variable `ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH` to the value 1 before you run the query to avoid the problem.

```bash
# Open Terminal
export ORA_OCI_NO_OPTIMIZED_FETCH=1
# Then run your request
...
```

This has been reported earlier here: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/120